# how to decode a multi/single value in Json

Tags: json, go

I want to decode a request JSON that the value of a field could be a single string or array (list).

I know how to parse if separately. but I'm looking for a way to have a dynamic decoder to parse both of them.

The `value` field in the JSON is the case I'm talking about

Sample for single-value:

```
{
    "filter":{
        "op":"IN",
        "field":"name",
        "value": "testDuplicate"
    }
}
```

Sample for multi-value:

```
{
    "filter":{
        "op":"IN",
        "field":"name",
        "value":["testDuplicate","tt"]
    }
}
```

Structs for single value:

```
type DocumentTypeSearchRequest struct {
    Filter   DocTypeFilter `json:"filter"`
}
type DocTypeFilter struct {
    Op    string `json:"op"`
    Field string `json:"field"`
    Value string `json:"value"`
}
```

Structs for multi-value:

```
type DocumentTypeSearchRequest struct {
    Filter   DocTypeFilter `json:"filter"`
}
type DocTypeFilter struct {
    Op    string `json:"op"`
    Field string `json:"field"`
    Value []string `json:"value"`
}
```

One solution is to try to decode with one of them if failed use another one, but I'm not sure if that is the proper way to handle this problem.

Comment: @Jamiec one of them is **Value []string `json:"value"`** and another one is **Value string `json:"value"`**
does it make sense?

Comment: @super please take a look at my comment. of they are a slice of string and another one is just a string

Comment: No, because your json input always has an array of values in the json (was one of them supposed to just have a single value? if not what do you intend to do with the rest?)

Comment: @Jamiec the `value` field is the matter here.
is some request it is only a string. in some requests, it is a list of strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a custom unmarshaler.  I've talked about a similar situation [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vsN11YAEJHY&t=6m35s):

```golang
type Value []string

func (v *Value) UnmarshalJSON(p []byte) error {
    if p[0] == '[' { // First char is '[', so it's a JSON array
        s := make([]string, 0)
        err := json.Unmarshal(p, &s)
        *v = Value(s)
        return err
    }
    // else it's a simple string
    *v = make(Value, 1)
    return json.Unmarshal(p, &(*v)[0])
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/IQRsvVK41qu)

With this definition of `Value`, your struct would become something like:

```golang
type DocTypeFilter struct {
    Op    string `json:"op"`
    Field string `json:"field"`
    Value Value  `json:"value"`
}
```

and now your `Value` field will always be a slice, but it may contain only a single value when your JSON input is a string, and not an array.

Comment: I'm not sure this works quite how you thought (Or, more likely being a Go newbie I'm not able to adjust your solution which I'm just using as a learning point!) `cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field DocTypeFilter.filter.value of type []main.Value` [playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/34jFcAV02_D)

Comment: Don't use `[]Value`, use `Value`. `Value` itself is now a slice, so `[]Value` is a slice of slices (not what you want).

Comment: @Flimzy thanks for the solution. I tried it with my case `{"filter":{"op":"EQ","field":"name","value":"testDuplicate"},"page":0,"page_size":0} json but it returns error. could you please update the playground with the sample too?
many thanks.

Comment: You mean like this? https://play.golang.org/p/H_CcSaG-rmz

Comment: @Flimzy I meant a solution that parse the sample  json comes in the question . this 

"{"filter":{"op":"EQ","field":"name","value":"testDuplicate"},"page":0,"page_size":0}".

full json